# Can we still use login-processing-url attribute in spring security?

Tags: java, spring

[Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-form-login) says that

> login-processing-url
>
> Maps to the filterProcessesUrl property of
>   UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter. The default value is
>   "/j_spring_security_check".

But look at the [AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html#getFilterProcessesUrl%28%29). It said that the method was deprecated. So what should we use instead? How can we specify the `login-processing-url` now?

Comment: Not 100% sure about the version, I am using it with the latest version, 3.1.2-RELEASE I guess

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj Are you that the version is the latest version? The javadoc is from the 3.2.4 version.

Comment: Just verified : I am using it with 3.2.0-RELEASE. Will have to check with 3.2.4-RELEASE

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj It seems I found the answer. At the [sources](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java) of the class we can find that the get method is missed at all, but we can still set that property correctly. Another question is whether we can pass ant-path like `/**` into that property? What dou you think?

Comment: Why would you do that (doesn't sound right), its a login-processing url, not an interceptor pattern

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj Well, I'd say to configure authentication.

Comment: Give me an example what you are trying to achieve by having a pattern in place of exact url.

Comment: Have you read the documentation you yourself pointed to? The [`setFilterProcessUrl`] tells you what to use. Next to that the documentation is wrong as the setter isn't used anymore but the updated method as explained in the javadoc. So in short you can still use the same way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use login-processing-url something like this -

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
      <intercept-url pattern="/secured/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login login-processing-url="/login" login-page="/loginPage"
            username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"
            default-target-url="/secured/mypage" authentication-failure-url="/loginPage?auth=fail" />
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/logoutPage" />        
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="srccodes" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: The question was not about how I can use it. It was about the method that was deprecated.

Comment: Ok. I actually responded since you mentioned  > How can we specify the login-processing-url now?